# QuietJs - Ionic 3 error

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am trying to implement the quietjs library into un ionic project, but I have un error that I cannot understand.

Here is my code:

app.html

```
 <ion-fab bottom center>
        <button ion-button block (tap)="sendQuietData()">
            Send
        </button>
    </ion-fab>
```

app.ts

```
//button acction for sending data
sendQuietData() {
    this.initQuiet();
    Quiet.transmitter({profile: 'ultrasonic', onFinish: this.onTransmitFinish}).transmit(Quiet.str2ab('example text'));

}


//initialize quietjs library
initQuiet() {
    Quiet.init({
        profilesPrefix: "/assets/data",
        memoryInitializerPrefix: "/assets/data",
        libfecPrefix: "/assets/data"
    });

    Quiet.addReadyCallback(this.onQuietReady, this.onQuietFail);
}

//setting up the profile
onQuietReady() {

    Quiet.transmitter({profile: 'ultrasonic', onFinish: this.onTransmitFinish});

};

//on failure log it in console
onQuietFail(reason) {
    console.log("quiet failed to initialize: " + reason);
};

//on finish log it in the console
onTransmitFinish() {
    console.log("quiet finished transmiting: ");
};
```

The error I get is this:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at lengthBytesUTF8 (quiet-emscripten.js:1)
    at Object.intArrayFromString (quiet-emscripten.js:1)
    at Object.transmitter (quiet.js:281)
    at AppPage.webpackJsonp.115.AppPage.sendData (app.ts:69)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (AppPage.html:8)
    at handleEvent (core.js:13589)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:15098)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:14685)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:10004)
    at core.js:10629
```

Does anyone have encountered this error, or is there un example on how to implement quietjs, on an Ionic app.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have manage to have this working, I am going to leave this here in case someone else wants to know how to do it.

First of all, create a folder in src/assets called quiet (or whatever you want but remember to modify the path of the included files in index.html) the path will be src/assets/quiet

Copy the quiet.js and the quiet-emscripten.js in the src/assets/quiet folder created

Copy quiet-emscripten.js.mem script into the www folder

Put in your www/index.html this code below:

1. In between head tags it will look something like this:
   script data-ionic="inject">
   (function(w){var i=w.Ionic=w.Ionic||{};i.version='3.9.2';i.angular='5.2.5';i.staticDir='build/';})(window); 
   /script>

2.after the ...ion-app> tag you will have to include the libraries

```
<ion-app></ion-app>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/quiet/quiet.js"></script
<script async type="text/javascript" src="assets/quiet/quiet-emscripten.js"></script>
<script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>
```

3. Put in your .ts file where you are going to use the library 
   declare var Quiet: any;

This is it, doing this you should have the library working without any problem.